# Trouble with XSetSelectionOwner

Tags: copy-paste, xlib

I have an application in which one opens many windows. I added copy/paste, using XA_PRIMARY.

That works fine within my application. It also works fine when copying from other applications (pluma, FireFox, mate terminal) into a window of my application.

When I call XSetSelectionOwner(), with time stamp etc as explained in the documentation, server acknowledges new owner. That is, XGetSelectionOwner() returns the owner I just set.

However, when copying from my app to other applications I do not receive SelectionRequest.

From what I see, server only sets the owner for the Display used in the call XSetSelectionOwner().

Is this how it is supposed to work? Then, is there something else to do so server sets owner for all apps?

Comment: "server only sets the owner for the Display used in the call XSetSelectionOwner". This makes little sense. `Display` is your connection to the server. An X server can only work with one server, namely itself.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/CtfuPEqU) is a working example of an X11 selection owner, stolen from some ancient non-working source and beaten into submission by me. It only owns a single selection, a string "It Works\n". You can run it and see that it receives `SelectionRequest` events jolly well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your example. The absurd statement I made was the result of frustration, what I was seeing, and equally absurd statement in documentaiton: "If the time in the SetSelectionOwner request is in the future relative to the server's current time or is in the past relative to the last time the specified selection changed hands, the SetSelectionOwner request appears to the client to succeed, but ownership is not actually transferred.". So, what does "appears to succeed mean"? I am still working on it.

Comment: I get current owner via XGetSelectionOwner(), before calling XSetSelectionOwner(), and then after that. Server indicates that ownership has been changed. But except windows in my application, no other application honors that. How does this make sense? To solve a problem first I must have a way of knowing what is wrong. That, I have not found yet.

Comment: Does my example program work on your machine? If so, can you modify it such that it reproduces your behaviour? After doing that you should either understand why it does not work, or be able to post it here as a [mcve]. If it does not work for you, please explain exactly what the symptoms are, down to which keys/buttons you press where.

Comment: OK, I will do that. I did not try the example because I saw no difference. I will need some more time before posting a minimal sample as that is not really easy. Thank you.

Comment: At least I can ask the following for now. I get the current owner prior to calling XSetSelectionOwner(), then I do it again, after. I see the ownership has changed. So, why that is not acknowledged by other applications other than mine? When server says here is new owner, is it playing game?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "acknowledged by other applications". How do you know what they acknowledge? Do you debug them?

Comment: You are right. All I am saying though is that, everything works fine among windows of my app, but other apps do no seem to be aware that my app is the owner. I am still lost and trying to understand the behavior I am seeing. I will say less because it makes no sense to me either. Thanks.

Comment: There is more than one selection in X11. Normal applications usually work with two, PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD, and sometimes SECONDARY. Which selection do you assert? Which selection your other applications use? Do a quick check on the command line with the xclip utility. `xclip -o -selection primary` and `xclip -o -selection clipboard` should tell you

Comment: My bash does not find "xclip" command. However, within code I have been printing all those. I am using PRIMARY (XA-PRIMARY), as does pluma, terminal and FireFox. Also, the call XSetSelectionOwner() is not complex at all, and I do XFlush() after that. Indeed, even server tells me ownership has changed, via XGetSelectionOwner(). So, what can be wrong? Add to that, I can copy from any of these to my app. Seriously, this sounds like a joke or something (for more than a week). Thanks for trying to help. I will answer all your questions.

Comment: You can install xclip from source or from your package manager. Test my program. Does it work?

Comment: I will be doing that.

Comment: After running your example, I tried to copy in a pluma window, I get "No String", and copy does not take place. As for my app, I bring it up, make a selection to see who current owner is, and then make my app new onwer. I close the app, and repeat. This time server shows 0 for an owner (just before I call XSetSelectionOwner). That means, when I closed my app, server set owner to None. So, it knows about my ownership. Thus, the question is, why not receiving requests (the original question).

Comment: I don't know what is pluma. "No string" means the other program tries to paste something that is not a string (image or something else). You can open the code, add a line to print the atom, see what it tries to paste. My program only advertises that it can provide a string, not something else, so it's pluma's fault. You can try and paste to your terminal or to a text editor such as gedit or kate. As for your program, I haven't a slightest idea what it does. You are not showing any code. How can I possibly know what you are doing wrong?

Comment: OK I can reproduce this with chrome, it tries to paste targets TEXT, UTF8_STRING, text/plain and text/plain;charset=utf-8, but not STRING. It is easy to modify the program to provide all these targets (the actual data is the same in each case). With the modified program chrome is able to paste the text. [Modified program](https://pastebin.com/Anm4hGH7)

Comment: You are right, those are the targets, which at this time is not a concern anyway. As far as showing code, all I am doing is: XSetSelectionOwner(dsp, XA_PRIMARY, win, CurrentTime); and even, it all works within. There is no mask to set anywhere for receiving SelectionRequest, specifically. Is there some other reason that I might not receive a request? Well, I will keep working on it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: SelectionRequest and SelectionNotify cannot be masked, your window always gets them.

Comment: You know, if server behavior was somewhat consistent I could think of something. So, I make a selection in my app, and paste it in some other window in my app. I receive the request, all is good. Then, I try to paste into any other app, I do not receive a request, instead they paste something else. I come back and paste in my app, still it is the same selection, and works fine. I cannot think of what could be wrong unless I see a consistent behavior. Either I receive, or I do not. That has been the most frustrating.

Comment: Your program has a bug somewhere. That's all I can tell. I have no idea what kind of bug because you are not showing any code. Good luck with your quest.

Comment: Thank you. Would you happen to know what ".PN" means In: "If the specified selection has an owner, the X server sends a .PN SelectionRequest event to that owner."? Also, I have checked the fields of SelectionRequest, it is never sent. It seems that server generates it, rather than sending it.

Comment: looks like a troff formatting code, should not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Given the behavior of the Server, I had to assume that other clients are not making their request for "PRIMARY". So, I added "CLIPBOARD", and now everything is working great.
The documentation appears to say that every client will use PRIMARY. Further reading seems to indicate that there is a difference between making a "selection", and "copying text". They seem to skirt this as a useful feature. I see nothing but confusion. Anyway, there really was no bug in my app. I think documentation should have a line saying: You must implement both, PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD. That was the problem.